# Neural Network not fitting XOR

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave, backpropagation

I created an Octave script for training a neural network with 1 hidden layer using backpropagation but it can not seem to fit an XOR function.

- `x` Input 4x2 matrix `[0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]`
- `y` Output 4x1 matrix `[0; 1; 1; 0]`
- `theta` Hidden / output layer weights
- `z` Weighted sums
- `a` Activation function applied to weighted sums
- `m` Sample count (`4` here)

My weights are initialized as follows

```
epsilon_init = 0.12;
theta1 = rand(hiddenCount, inputCount + 1) * 2 * epsilon_init * epsilon_init;
theta2 = rand(outputCount, hiddenCount + 1) * 2 * epsilon_init * epsilon_init;
```

Feed forward

```
a1 = x;
a1_with_bias = [ones(m, 1) a1];
z2 = a1_with_bias * theta1';
a2 = sigmoid(z2);
a2_with_bias = [ones(size(a2, 1), 1) a2];
z3 = a2_with_bias * theta2';
a3 = sigmoid(z3);
```

Then I compute the logistic cost function

```
j = -sum((y .* log(a3) + (1 - y) .* log(1 - a3))(:)) / m;
```

Back propagation

```
delta2 = (a3 - y);
gradient2 = delta2' * a2_with_bias / m;

delta1 = (delta2 * theta2(:, 2:end)) .* sigmoidGradient(z2);
gradient1 = delta1' * a1_with_bias / m;
```

The gradients were verified to be correct using gradient checking.

I then use these gradients to find the optimal values for theta using gradient descent, though using Octave's `fminunc` function yields the same results. The cost function converges to `ln(2)` (or `0.5` for a squared errors cost function) because the network outputs `0.5` for all four inputs no matter how many hidden units I use.

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

Comment: Please show weight initialisation (start value for `theta`). At a guess, that could be your problem. I'll explain if so.

Comment: `epsilon_init = 0.12;`
`theta1 = rand(hiddenCount, inputCount + 1) * 2 * epsilon_init * epsilon_init;`
`theta2 = rand(outputCount, hiddenCount + 1) * 2 * epsilon_init * epsilon_init;`    Don't know how to format it correctly in a comment sorry about that!

Comment: I was wrong on my hunch, but at least now I can see if I replicate your results

Comment: I tried again and it does actually not work on OR and AND, though it converges to different values then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with a larger range when initialising weights, including negative values. It is difficult for your code to "cross-over" between positive and negative weights, and you probably meant to put `* 2 * epsilon_init - epsilon_init;` when instead you put `* 2 * epsilon_init * epsilon_init;`. Fixing that may well fix your code.

As a rule of thumb, I would do something like this:

```
theta1 = ( 0.5 * sqrt ( 6 / ( inputCount + hiddenCount) ) * 
    randn( hiddenCount, inputCount + 1 ) );
theta2 = ( 0.5 * sqrt ( 6 / ( hiddenCount + outputCount ) ) * 
    randn( outputCount, hiddenCount + 1 ) );
```

The multiplier is just some advice I picked up on a course, I think that it is backed by a research paper that compared a few different approaches.

In addition, you may need a *lot* of iterations to learn XOR if you run basic gradient descent. I suggest running for at least 10000 before declaring that learning isn't working. The `fminunc` function should do better than that.

I ran *your* code with 2 hidden neurons, basic gradient descent and the above initialisations, and it learned XOR correctly. I also tried adding momentum terms, and the learning was faster and more reliable, so I suggest you take a look at that next.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize it would take _that_ many iterations. Thanks for the advice I will look into momentum terms next!

Comment: I did not realize this either and I thank you so much for this.

Comment: Indeed, this is the so-called Glorot initialization by Glorot et al. (http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a.html), see for example https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotUniform

Answer (score 1):

You need at least 3 neurons in the hidden layer and correct the initialization as the first answer suggest.
If the sigmoidGradient(z2) means a2.*(1-a2) all the rest of the code seems ok to me.

Best reggards,